# Ldap over ssl not working

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ldap

I have configured AD DS, DNS and AD CS in windows server 2012 R2. I have restarted machine after configured.

I can able to connect with ldap on port 389 using ldp.exe.

When trying to connect with 636 port, i am getting below exception.

```
0x0 = ldap_unbind(ld);
ld = ldap_sslinit("machine1", 636, 1);
Error 0 = ldap_set_option(hLdap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
Error 81 = ldap_connect(hLdap, NULL);
Server error: <empty>
Error <0x51>: Fail to connect to machine1.
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any firewall in the server?

Comment: No firewall. It is in off state.

Comment: Did you make sure the LDAPS is listening to port 636? I hope you might have looked into https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/321051

Comment: Now its working... But actually don't know why it didn't worked yesterday and working today without any issue. I just confused.